# Seize Block not able to grab Resource

Tags: resources, anylogic

I have a test model simulating a simple rail yard operations. I am trying to simulate two train operations competing for one resource (locomotive engine).
The first 'seize' block is able to grab the resource and complete its operation but the second seize block ('seize1') is not able to grab hold of the resource pool even after it has been released.

I am new to AnyLogic and appreciative of any inputs or insights on how to make this work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoIjN.png)

Tried to model multiple train operations vying to use the same resource to complete their operation (locomotive engine).

Expected that one of the operations will seize the engine, complete the operation and release the engine back for the other operation.  However, the second operation is not able to seize the released resource (engine).

Comment: are you customizing the resource selection in any way?

Comment: yeah, pls show how you setup _both_ `Seize` blocks, hard to advice otherwise

Comment: Hi Guys, Thank you for your interest.  I was able to figure it out.  Just an error from someone new to AnyLogic.  Turns out I had the 'traincouple' and 'traindecouple' blocks set in the wrong way such that the agent that was passing through the 'seize' block was never reaching the 'release' block and therefore the resource was not being released.  Just something to keep in mind in future when developing complicated train operation flowcharts with 'seize' and 'release' elements.